# Is it possible to list variable names of a struct in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, struct

if I have a struct say:

```
struct myStruct {
int someInt;
flot someFloat;
}
```

Is there any way to get a list of the member variables? ie. someInt, someFloat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not. Unlike Objective-C classes, structs don't save member names anywhere, they're only known to the compiler.